# How to center the <div> vertically?

Tags: css-selectors

This is my first ever project. I am using Bootstrap and some custom styling has been included.

This is my website: https://carwashwebsite.netlify.app/. If you refer to the image(taken from the website) below, I would like to make the rectangle at center vertically and horizontally for desktop and mobile views.

[Website Image Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8sNT.png)

Another thing is, please advise on what I can do for my tablet view? It looks weird.

Thanks

I tried using justify-content and align-items but I can't achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .center{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 300px;
            border: 2px solid red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
   <div class="center">
    <p>i am vartrically centerd</p>
   </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have tried your method before this, it doesn't work. 
here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/ahaar99/pen/ExRqQzJ
Please do check the link.

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer, @Dk Jangid.